# How to marginalise a vector with index?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have this code:

```
A = [3,1,5,8]
B = [0, 0]
indexB = [1,2,2,1]

for i = 1:4
  B(indexB(i)) = B(indexB(i)) + A(i)
end
```

So, in the end, I got

```
B = [11, 6]
```

I wonder if I can use a more efficient way to sum up instead of using the `for`-loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic use of [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).  Only this time, you accumulate the entries in `A` then add this on top of `B` as `B` is the starting point of the summation:

```
B = B(:); % Force into columns
B = B + accumarray(indexB(:), A(:));
```

How `accumarray` works is quite simple.  You can think of it as a miniature MapReduce paradigm. Simply put, for each data point we have, there is a key and an associated value. The goal of `accumarray` is to place (or bin) all of the values that belong to the same key and do some operation on all of these values. In our case, the "key" would be the values in `indexB` where each element is a location to index into `B`.  The values themselves are those from `A`.  We would then want to add up all of the values that belong to each location in `indexB` together. Thankfully, the default behaviour for accumarray is to add all of these values. Specifically, the output of accumarray would be an array where each position computes the sum of all values that mapped to a key. For example, the first position would be the summation of all values that mapped to the key of 1, the second position would be the summation of all values that mapped to the key of 2 and so on.

Because you are using `B` as a starting point, the end result would be to take the summation result from `accumarray` and add this on top of `B` thus completing the code.

## Minor Note

I do have to point out that `accumarray` works by **columns**.  Because you are using rows, I had to force the input so that they are columns, which is the purpose of the `(:)` syntax.  The output will also be as a column so you can transpose that if you wish to have it in a row format.

Comment: I got error message:

Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: @lanselibai Check my edit.  `accumarray` requires columns but you're using rows.  I have to write code to force it into columns to make sure that it works.

Comment: No problem :) I'm writing some more explanation to give you a sense of how `accumarray` works.  Right now it looks like it's magic.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, this is exactly what I want!

Comment: @lanselibai You're very welcome :) Glad I could help.  Good luck!